# ARC Memory allocation with CCParticleSystemQuad

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I use ARC for memory management.

Before the begining of the game I use a preload scene in which I load a lot of CCParticleSystemQuad object that I'll use in my game. All is going well in this part, here is my code :

```
//
//  ReadySteadyGo.m

//
//  Created by Nik on 23/05/13.
//  Copyright 2013 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ReadySteadyGoLayer.h"
#import "QuickStartLayer.h"


@implementation ReadySteadyGoLayer
// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the ReadySteadyLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    ReadySteadyGoLayer *layer = [ReadySteadyGoLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
@synthesize particleExplosion;


// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        compteur = 3;
        plus10LablesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:400];
        whiteParticlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:500];
        bombParticlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
        self.particleExplosion = [[CCParticleSystemQuad alloc] init];
        bombExplosion = [[CCParticleSystemQuad alloc] init];
        plus10Label = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] init];
        displayCompteur = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] init];
        self.particleExplosion = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"whiteExplosion.plist"];
        bombExplosion = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"explosion.plist"];
    }

    [self schedule:@selector(initAll)];
    [self schedule:@selector(compt)];
    return self;
}

-(void)initAll{
    // Create a new NSOperationQueue instance.
    operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    // Create a new NSOperation object using the NSInvocationOperation subclass.
    // Tell it to run the counterTask method.
    NSInvocationOperation *operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(initWhiteParticles)
                                                                              object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                             selector:@selector(initBombParticles)
                                                                               object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation3 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                             selector:@selector(initPlus10Labels)
                                                                               object:nil];
    // Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation1];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation2];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation3];
    [self unschedule:@selector(initAll)];

}

- (void)compt{
   CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    if (compteur == 3){
        displayCompteur = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i...", compteur] fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:120];
        displayCompteur.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:displayCompteur z:1000];
        compteur--;
        [self unschedule:@selector(compt)];
        [self schedule:@selector(boucle) interval:1.0f];
    }
    else if (compteur == 2){
        displayCompteur.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i..", compteur];
        compteur--;
        [self schedule:@selector(compt) interval:1.0f];
    }
    else if (compteur == 1){
        displayCompteur.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.", compteur];
        compteur--;
        [self schedule:@selector(compt) interval:1.0f];
    }
    else if (compteur == 0){
        displayCompteur.string  = @"GO";
        displayCompteur.fontSize = 25;
        compteur--;
        [self schedule:@selector(compt) interval:1.0f];
    }
    else{
        [self unschedule:@selector(compt)];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[QuickStartLayer scene:plus10LablesArray:whiteParticlesArray: bombParticlesArray]];
    }
```

}

```
- (void)initWhiteParticles{ 
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < 500; index++) {
        self.particleExplosion = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"whiteExplosion.plist"];
        [whiteParticlesArray  performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addObject:) withObject:self.particleExplosion waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

- (void)initBombParticles{
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
        bombExplosion = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"explosion.plist"];
        [bombParticlesArray  performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addObject:) withObject:bombExplosion waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

- (void)initPlus10Labels{
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < 400; index++) {
        plus10Label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"+10" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20];
        [plus10LablesArray performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addObject:) withObject:plus10Label waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

@end
```

The problem is when I check in Instruments (allocations) I can see [CCParticleSystemQuad alloc memory] increasing each time. After 15 min of using my game, it crashes...

When I use on of my particle I do this :

```
explosion = [_whiteParticlesArray objectAtIndex:nextWhiteParticle];
nextWhiteParticle++;
explosion.position = ccp(posX, posY);
[particleToDelete addObject:explosion];
[self addChild: explosion];
```

I created a function to clean the particles which is :

```
- (void)cleanParticles{
    for (int i = 0; i < [particleToDelete count]; i++) {
        id object = [particleToDelete objectAtIndex:i];
        [particleToDelete removeObject:object];
        [self removeChild:object cleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

At the end of the game here is what I do :

```
[self unschedule:@selector(countDown:)];
[self unschedule:@selector(addAllSprites:)]
[self unschedule:@selector(displayScore:)];
[self unschedule:@selector(cleanParticles)];
[self unschedule:@selector(cleanLabels)];
[_whiteParticlesArray removeAllObjects];
[_bombParticlesArray removeAllObjects];
[_plus10LabelsArray removeAllObjects];
[self removeChild:_spriteSheet cleanup:YES];
```

So I remove all objects, and ARC is supposed to clean the memory of those objects right ? The problem is that it does not.

Thank you for your help guys :).

**Edit 1**:

I am really stuck ... I remove all my objects which are in my NSMutableArray but ARC does not deallocate them. Someone for help ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

That one seems obvious. You have all particles stored in `_whiteParticlesArray`, right? So as long as the particles are still in that array, they will be retained by the array and remain in memory.

When you remove all objects and memory usage does not change (significantly) in Instruments you may be having other leaks too. One thing you should check in Instruments is how many of the particle objects are alive. And be sure to verify that the scene instance itself is deallocated after changing scenes.

Btw, it's not very effective to create hundreds of particle systems in advance. Do you have a performance problem when you create the particles when needed? If not, create them on the fly.  Keep in mind that each particle system itself uses around 500 bytes so 500 particle systems amount to roughly 250 KB just for the class instances.

You can still preload the textures, which is the most important part. All you need to do is to create one of each particle type that uses an embedded texture, or use texture cache to preload the textures of particle system plists without embedded textures.

Comment: I checked in instruments and I do not have leaks... Ok I'll check how many particles objects are alive. Of which scene are you talking about? My preload scene or my game scene? Yeah I had performance problem, because in my game once the user touches the screen there is a particle effect. And if you touch many times the screen, the FPS dip down (around 25 FPS), now it's around (55-60). I tried to use a particle system manager but I had a problem with it, with my addChild. Indeed, I can not add the same CCParticleSystemQuad. I do not see how to do your last advice. Thx a lot, I appreciate.